# Network access sometimes lost, disabling port security temporary solves?

Tags: port, mac-address, switch

I have network based primarily on Edge-Core managed switched.

Port security with max mac count = 1 is enabled, DHCP snoopping enabled.
Some clients have troubles with accesing network, but when I disable port security on switch connection to network resumes. When I apply port security again connection works normally for about one or two days or less. While doing this client is not reqesting new ip address from dhcp.

In switch logs I've found nothing bad, no connection breakings.
Can someone give me advise how to shoot this problem, or maybe an idea where to go.

Comment: Anyone running a client-based hypervisor such as VMWare Fusion/Workstation or that bloody-awful virtualised-XP in Vista? They can generate a second MAC down the link you see.

Comment: No second mac is not the case, because I will have in my logs messages like 14:18:46 Unit 1 port  1 have intrusion MAC 00195B-68B145.